# Changing Vimeo Embed background color (the black bars that happen when embedding a non-16:9 video in a 16:9 frame) using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, embed, elementor, vimeo

I'm looking for a way to change the background color of a Vimeo Embed using CSS. The reason why I need this specific solution is because I'm changing the Vimeo Link in the Embed dynamically with Elementor Posts. This will result in different aspect ratios that will all have to fit into this 16:9 frame. Hence I cannot cut off the bottom and top part of the frame, as this will also cut off video in for example 4:3 videos.

I have tried inspecting the element in Google Chrome to see if I can figure out which element I need to access, but it's not clear to me what I have to do.

Comment: Embedded video's such as vimeo create their own html document inside of your website/ webpage. Changing styling inside that html document is not possible, because it is outside of your page. I've tried many times and in many ways to manipulate the data coming from these html documents. But there are no fixes sadly. What you could do however is change the embed settings via vimeo itself, however, some of these settings cost money.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="vimeo-player"></div>

<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<script>
  // Replace "YOUR_VIDEO_ID" with your actual Vimeo video ID
  var videoId = "YOUR_VIDEO_ID";
  var player = new Vimeo.Player('vimeo-player', {
    id: videoId,
    autoplay: false,
    loop: false,
  });

  // Change the background color of the Vimeo embed
  player.on('ready', function() {
    var iframe = document.querySelector('#vimeo-player iframe');
    iframe.style.backgroundColor = '#your-color';
  });
</script>
```

I use the Vimeo Player API to create a new player instance and target the vimeo-player div element as the container for the embed. Replace "YOUR_VIDEO_ID" with the actual Vimeo video ID you want to embed.

After the player is ready, the player.on('ready') event listener is triggered. Inside this event listener, we select the Vimeo embed iframe using document.querySelector('#vimeo-player iframe'). Then, we set the backgroundColor CSS property of the iframe to the desired color using iframe.style.backgroundColor = '#your-color'.

By modifying the background color of the Vimeo embed dynamically through JavaScript, you can adjust it based on the aspect ratio of the video and ensure it fits into your 16:9 frame without cutting off any parts of the video.

Comment: This is really clever. Thanks! How do I adjust the size of the player to fit 100% of my wrapper div? And is it possible to hide elements of the Vimeo Player hud?